# How do you change the coordinates of a UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uiimageview, coordinates

I have made a `UIImageView` show an image of my choosing in Interface Builder.

In code, I want to find a way to change the x and y coordinates of this image view, during the program.

Is it possible to do that?

I've already made a variable

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *Alan;
```

but am not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Change view's `frame` property:

```
Alan.frame = (CGRect){{newX, newY}, Alan.frame.size};
// same as 
// Alan.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, Alan.frame.size.width, Alan.frame.size.height);
```

or if you want to set position of view center:

```
Alan.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
```

**P.S.** Note also that per objective-c naming guidelines instance variable names should start with lowercase.